# How do i call a php function inside the Jquery Code

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a php function which get the Details when passed an number .So, i have a dynamic table where each row contains insert button 
which performs some action on the row record .Now Here i have to call php function getdetails and pass the data-number and get the details from the function
and create an array insert in to session

```
  $(".bttn_insert").live('click',function(){
       var data-number = $(this).attr('data-number');
       //Now Here i have to call php function getdetails and pass the data-number and get the details from the function
       and create an array insert in to session 
       <?php getdetails('data-number'),?>

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax as descibe in other post, but this is what code you would need to do:

```
$(".bttn_insert").live('click',
    function()
    {
       var post_data = {
           data_number:$(this).attr('data-number')
       }
       $.post('getdetails.php',post_data,function(data){
           //Gets called upon completion.
           $('#some_selector p').html(data);
       })
    }
);
```

and the PHP file, depending on the way your configuration is:

```
<?php
//include 'your functions';
//or
/*
    function getDetails(){...}
*/

if(!empty($_POST['data_number']))
{
    if(is_numeric($_POST['data_number']))
    {
        echo getDetails( (int)$_POST['data_number'] );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use AJAX e.g. $.ajax, $.get, $.post

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

In your PHP file just echo the result you want to receive.

Read more: [[**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)]

Comment: Instead of echoing plain text, it's often better to use JSON which support string/numeric/boolean/array/object types. Just use `echo json_encode($data);` and add the parameter `dataType: 'json'` to the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Yes you are right, JSON should be used, so you can all kind of data as stated above.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is executed on the client, and PHP is executed on the server, therefore you need to make a call to the server, for example though AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to use a php function directly from jquery, you have to create a php script to encapsulate your function call then call your php script via jquery ajax functions.

If you want to insert php calls to generate javascript code this is a different issue as I don't think thatgenerating directly into your jquery code would be a good idea, you should probably generate a separated jsonp output from your php then use the object in jquery.

Comment: This is in case you want to output JavaScript through PHP file.